# JButton text changes on its own?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, border-layout

The following simple code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ButtonTextMain {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            
            final JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
            
            final JButton button = new JButton("Click to change text");
            button.addActionListener(e -> button.setText(field.getText()));
            
            final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

can always reproduce the same bug (at least for my setups, which are given below).

The program is supposed to change the button text, according to the text-field's text, when the button is clicked.

The problem is that the text of the button reverts/changes back to its previous value on its own unexpectedly.

The problem arises when I use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> to alternate/navigate between the button and the text-field. Here are the specific steps which always reproduce the same bug on my setups:

1. Run the program.
2. Resize the frame to be a bit bigger than it was.
3. Type some short text in the text-field.
4. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate the focus to the button.
5. Press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to invoke the button.
6. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate the focus back to the text-field.
7. Type any letter you like into the text-field.

Notes:

- I know that step 2 is relevant, because if I ommit it then the bug does not reproduce.
- After step 2 (and before 3), the mouse should not be needed any more. Leave it. The focus of the program should be in the text-field as it was when the program launched.
- In step 3 I usually type something like `abc` but the error repoduces for any other input I tried.
- In step 6 you can also use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate back to the text-field.
- On step 7, after typing the first letter, you will see that the button's text changes back to its initial/previous value.

My first tested setup:

- Apache NetBeans IDE 8.2, which is a bit outdated.
- `java -version` yields:

  ```
  java version "1.8.0_321"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)
  ```
- `javac -version` yields `javac 1.8.0_161`. There is a missmatch here with the runtime environment.

My second tested setup:

- Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0.
- `java -version` yields:

  ```
  java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
  ```
- `javac -version` yields `javac 12.0.2`.

The operating system is Windows 10 on both setups.

So the question is: did I do something wrong, and if so, what is it please? First of, can anybody else reproduce the bug I am getting on their setup?

#### Update:

I can also reproduce this behaviour on the system L&F too, by using:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

inside just before the `JTextField` creation (and catching exceptions, etc).

Comment: I do not have a problem and see no reason for a problem. The code follows basic Swing coding rules. I use Windows 10 and JDK 11.0.6.

Comment: @camickr so you can't reproduce it? I too really have no clue what is going wrong with it, but it does. On my system, I can always reproduce it. Thanks for reading/testing this.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug both with Java 1.8.0_201 and Java 17.0.2. I get the exact same behavior that you describe when I perform the steps outlined in your question. Also, after step 7 I press TAB to navigate back to the `JButton` and the text changes to what it was after step 5. My guess is that it has something to do with the UI classes like `BasicButtonUI` and maybe also with the fact that the `JTextField` and `JButton` are not at their preferred sizes. Maybe you should file a bug? My workaround is to ensure that the components are always displayed with their preferred sizes.

Comment: @Abra thank you for confirming and testing! I was really hoping someone could reproduce and not it being my own system's missbehaviour. Your suggested workaround though would mean that I would have an infexible layout, throwing away the whole point of layout managers. Or maybe did you mean something else? Also, I don't know how to file a bug: can you suggest me where is the proper place to do it? I will/should wait though for some time before filing.

Comment: Just Google for **file java bug**. A `JTextField` is for entering a single line of text and therefore not suitable for resizing, in my opinion. I would use a [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) instead of a `JTextField`. In fact, I cannot reproduce the bug if I replace `JTextField` with `JTextArea` in your code.

Comment: Curiously, I cannot reproduce this on the command-line, using Java 17.0.2 in Windows 10.  Could it be an issue with Apache NetBeans?

Comment: @VGR thank you for testing this. I can reproduce it though even with the command line (using Java 12 - both JRE and compiler). I have no idea if it is an issue with the IDE, but running completely from command line reproduces, so the IDE might not be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above comments I retested and now I am able to reproduce the problem. The issue occurs when you increase the vertical height of the text field (by some minimal amount).

I guess I tested before by only increasing the horizontal size of the text field.

I found a simple work around:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ButtonTextMain {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            final JTextField field = new JTextField(20);

            final JButton button = new JButton("Click to change text");
            button.addActionListener(e ->
            {
                button.setText(field.getText());
                //button.getParent().revalidate();
                button.getParent().repaint();
            });

            final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setContentPane(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

This definitely seems like a bug to me.

Having said that, rarely would you want the vertical height of the text field to increase in size. So maybe you can find a layout manager that only affects the horizontal size and not the vertical height?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes then, I will either use your workaround, or the suggestion about the layout manager.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have this problem.
I use VScode, java version 1.8.0.25.
I think problem is your compiler.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your time. Did you follow exactly the steps to reproduce? Are you referring as 1.8.0.25 to *JRE* or `javac` or both? But then I tried version 12 too (both JRE and compiler same version), so why does it not work on 12?

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.  Having insufficient reputation to write comments is not an excuse for using an answer for something that should be a comment.